# Components cutting off on different platforms with MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I'm wondering what the best practices are when sizing components for multiple platforms when using `MigLayout`.

Specifically I am having a problem when using the `"Height 20!"` type component constraints. When testing on different L&F's and platforms, the components will sometimes be cut off, or `JButton` text will display as `".."`. I try to avoid using these constraints as much as possible, but sometimes it seems to be the only way to do what I'm trying to do. Are there any other recommended practices I should be considering?

Buttons being added like:

```
add(backButton, "h 32!, w 37!");
```

for example

Comment: *"Are there any other recommended practices I should be considering?"*  1) Call `pack()` on the top level container after all components are added.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: _sometimes it seems to be the only way to do what I'm trying to do_ show an example which seems to need it, and chances are that someone here can show you an alternative _without_ hard-coded sizes